# How to find and append gene name based on overlapping chr start and stop positions?

Tags: r, range

I have df1:

```
1 25 85
1 2000 3000
2 345 2300
```

And df2:

```
1 34 45 geneX
1 100 1000 geneD
2 456 1500 geneH
```

The desired output:

```
1 25 85 geneX
1 2000 3000 NA
2 345 2300 geneH
```

I have tried in two ways:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = names(df1))
setDT(df2, key = key(df1))
overlaps <- foverlaps(df1, df2, type = "any", nomatch = 0L)[, -c("chromosome","start", "stop")]
```

This above code gives me some region multiple times...

```
rangesC <- NULL
sb <- NULL
sb$gene <- NULL
for(i in levels(df1$chromosome)){
  sb <- subset(df1, df1$chromosome == i)
  s <- subset(df2, df2$chromosome == i)
  for(j in 1:nrow(sb)){
    sb$gene[j] <- as.character(s$gene[which(s$start < sb$start[j] &  s$stop > sb$stop[j])])
  }
  rangesC <- rbind(rangesC, sb)
}
```

But this code is not working. I preferably would like to maintain and use the methods I tried above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the idea is that if one of your value in df1 falls within the  window of the gene in the df2, you want to assign the gene name in the df1?

Comment: exactly, my goal is to assign the gene name to the df1.

Comment: And 2nd question, is there an association between the rows in the two df?
Like, for the row 1 in df1, do you need to look in all the gene in df2  or only in the first row?

Comment: as soon as the genes are in the interval for that givend chromosome for me is fine

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, I use the library dplyr

Here the data you showed us:

```
a = matrix(c(25 ,85,
 2000 ,3000,
 345 ,2300),byrow = T,ncol = 2)

b =  matrix(c(34 ,45 ,'geneX',
 100, 1000 ,'geneD',
 456, 1500 ,'geneH'),ncol=3,byrow=T)
```

and here is my solution, I use a for loop:

```
res = matrix(ncol=3)[-1,]
if(nrow(a)==nrow(b)){
for(i in 1:nrow(a)){
  
  if(between(as.numeric(b[i,1]),a[i,1],a[i,2])&between(as.numeric(b[i,2]),a[i,1],a[i,2])){
    res= rbind(res, c(a[i,],b[i,3]))
  }else{
    res=rbind(res, c(a[i,],NA))
  }
  
}
}
res


#> res
#     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   
#[1,] "25"   "85"   "geneX"
#[2,] "2000" "3000" NA     
#[3,] "345"  "2300" "geneH"
```

I think you can remove all the as.numeric in your case cause your data seem to be already numerical

Answer (score 0):

You can `fuzzyjoin` package :

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, 
                           by = c('V1', 'V2', 'V3'), 
                           match_fun = c(`==`, `<=`, `>=`)) %>%
  dplyr::select(V1 = V1.x, V2 = V2.x, V3 = V3.x, V4)

#  V1   V2   V3    V4
#1  1   25   85 geneX
#2  1 2000 3000  <NA>
#3  2  345 2300 geneH
```

Comment: this gives me and error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 50.5 Gb

Answer (score 0):

A faster option would be a non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, on = .(V1, V2 <= V2, V3 >= V3)]
```